# Dimension change on np.array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Say we have a np.array of size (2, 2, 4):

```
my_array = np.array([[[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
                      [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]],

                     [[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
                      [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]]])
```

I can't figure how to obtain this array (of size (2, 2, 2, 2)) from the previous one, **it should contain the same data from *my_array*** :

```
np.array([[[[ 0.,  0.],
            [ 0.,  0.]],

           [[ 0.,  0.],
            [ 0.,  0.]]],


          [[[ 0.,  0.],
            [ 0.,  0.]],

           [[ 0.,  0.],
            [ 0.,  0.]]]])
```

I've tried [np.expand_dims](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html) :

```
new_array = np.expand_dims(my_array, axis=3)
```

But I got :

```
array([[[[ 0.],
         [ 0.],
         [ 0.],
         [ 0.]],

        [[ 0.],
         [ 0.],
         [ 0.],
         [ 0.]]],


       [[[ 0.],
         [ 0.],
         [ 0.],
         [ 0.]],

        [[ 0.],
         [ 0.],
         [ 0.],
         [ 0.]]]])
```

Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simplest to use [`reshape`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) for this task:

```
In [2]: my_array.reshape(2,2,2,2)
Out[2]: 
array([[[[ 0.,  0.],
         [ 0.,  0.]],

        [[ 0.,  0.],
         [ 0.,  0.]]],


       [[[ 0.,  0.],
         [ 0.,  0.]],

        [[ 0.,  0.],
         [ 0.,  0.]]]])
```

Whenever possible, using `reshape` will create a new view of the array (and not copy any underlying data). In this particular case, it has no difficulty in returning a new view with the required shape and number of dimensions.

If you're in any doubt as to whether reshaping will copy data, a useful method is to try and set the array's `.shape` attribute directly:

```
my_array.shape = (2,2,2,2)
```

If a reshape is not possible without copying data, NumPy will raise an error instead of copying.

Comment: That worked. Thanks to all the others who answered my question. I definitely should have a better look on the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You need `np.reshape` not `np.expand_dims`:

```
>>> my_array.reshape(2,2,2,2)
array([[[[ 0.,  0.],
         [ 0.,  0.]],

        [[ 0.,  0.],
         [ 0.,  0.]]],


       [[[ 0.,  0.],
         [ 0.,  0.]],

        [[ 0.,  0.],
         [ 0.,  0.]]]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the reshape command :

```
In [3]: a=np.arange(2*2*4).reshape(2,2,4)

In [4]: a
Out[4]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7]],

    [[ 8,  9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14, 15]]])

In [5]: a.reshape(2,2,2,2)
Out[5]: 
array([[[[ 0,  1],
        [ 2,  3]],

        [[ 4,  5],
        [ 6,  7]]],


    [[[ 8,  9],
        [10, 11]],

        [[12, 13],
        [14, 15]]]])
```